# Getting data that is more then or equal to in Postgres SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that uses postgres. My query needs to find the diffrence between the `started_at` time and `now()` and then only
select the data where the difference is >= 300 seconds.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT id, (extract(epoch from now()) - extract(epoch from started_at)) completed_time
FROM run_item WHERE started_at IS NOT NULL AND completed_at is NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried placing this expression the where clause?

```
SELECT * FROM run_item WHERE
(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now()) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM started_at)) >= 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

> find the diffrence between the started_at time and now() and then only select the data where the difference is >= 300 seconds

You could do date arithmetics as follows:

```
select id, started_at - now() diff
from run_item r
where started_at <= now() - interval '5' minutes
```

In the resultset, `diff` is a column of interval datatype.